# Suddenly net/http tls handshake timeout from Windows Server 2019 to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-ssm

We got the on-prem servers running in ESXi, a Windows Server 2019 with AWS SSM Agent and Cloudwatch log agent installed, it is running fine and event logs are collected properly.

Until these days, suddenly we keep seeing the error `net/http tls handshake timeout` when connecting to `logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` and `ssm.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did anybody in your on-premise servers installed a network firewall? Was the IAM credentials assigned to the on-premise machines still exists or does it still have sufficient IAM permissions to execute the logging and ssm operations mate?